# Creating Nested Object Property Names Dynamically in Javascript for Google Adwords Scripts (ES5)

Tags: javascript, object, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create a javascript object that contains nested properties where some of the property names need to be generated dynamically. The following is what I have that is already working:

```
postObject[campaignObj.campaignName] = {
    "campaignSet" : {
      "groupName" : groupObj.adGroupName,
      "textads" : groupObj.textAds
    }
}
```

However, I need "campaignSet" to be named dynamically from a variable or other object value. The possibility exists for several campaign sets to exist that must all be contained under postObject[campaignObj.campaignName].

My thought process was that something like the options below should work

```
postObject[campaignObj.campaignName] = {
    [campaignObj.campaignSet] : {
      "groupName" : groupObj.adGroupName,
      "textads" : groupObj.textAds
    }
}
```

but this code above keeps throwing an "Invalid property ID" error.

So I tried this

```
postObject[campaignObj.campaignName] = {
    campaignObj.campaignSet : {
      "groupName" : groupObj.adGroupName,
      "textads" : groupObj.textAds
    }
}
```

Which caused "Missing : after property ID".

I feel this should be pretty straightforward but it continues to elude me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, your first thought is valid ES6 :-)

Comment: Thanks Bergi, at least I know I'm not completely crazy lol.

Comment: Unfortunately, this javascript snippet is for Google Adwords Scripts which doesn't support ES6 just yet. Daniel's answer below works for Adwords Scripts which supports up to ES5 currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
postObject[campaignObj.campaignName] = postObject[campaignObj.campaignName] || {}; // in case is not defined

postObject[campaignObj.campaignName][campaignSetDynamicName] = {
  "groupName" : groupObj.adGroupName,
  "textads" : groupObj.textAds
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks Daniel.